Visual Studio code C++ autocomplete does not work for variables created with auto declarator
I am working on Visual Studio Code in a codebase with custom classes and when variables are declared using auto, my autocomplete will not work. Here is an example for a function returning a smart pointer to a custom class.
When using auto, I get "No suggestions"

If I manually declare the type, it works fine.

Is this a known issue? something I can try? Thank you.

visual studio code, sorry. edited. thank you.

how have you configured intellisense? are you using the c++ plugin intellisense or clang?

I use C/C++ Intellisense

Yes, this is a known problem, unfortunately, when using the auto type, visual studio cannot determine the method fields and their types for a class, as far as I know, the only way to return tooltips is to explicitly indicate the type

"this is a known problem" - do you have a source for that?

I myself worked in a visual studio and came across it
